# Cannot access Windows Server over wifi

Tags: networking, windows-10, lan, wireless-access-point, windows-server-2016

I have a server that I just set up running windows server 2016. My PC (windows 10) has network access via ethernet, it is able to see the server in the network section on my explorer. My computer and laptop (windows 10) are visible in the network section on the server. However, my laptop can see my PC and is able to ping the server but cannot see it in the network section. My laptop and PC are connected to the same AP but the server is connected to my main SOHO router. My server is setup for file sharing and I cannot access the drive on my laptop however I can remote connect. Why might this problem happen? Could it be a security setting? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: According to "Cannot access Windows Server over wifi", we cannot access Windows Server over wifi from laptop or PC?
Do we want to access shared folders or files on Windows Server over wifi?

According to "My server is setup for file sharing and I cannot access the drive on my laptop however I can remote connect" , where can not we access the drive on laptop （PC or Windows server）？
If the drive on my laptop is shared?

Comment: If AP and SOHO router are in the same segment(PC, laptop, Windows server)?
Try to turn off the Windows Defender firewall, turn on the network discovery on three devices(PC, laptop, Windows server).

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I was unclear: I cannot access the server over wifi from my laptop. I am trying to access files and folders on windows server over wifi. I cannot access the windows server drive FROM my laptop. I'm attempting to share the windows server disk. The laptop and PC are on the same segment but the server is on another, I figure if the PC can discover the server it's not a matter of the segment but I'm not sure.